# MYSQL Invalid use of group function How to resolve?

Tags: mysql

After creating trigger It started to displaying the Invalid use of group function error on update query.

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER header_true BEFORE UPDATE 
ON category 
FOR EACH row 
begin 
  IF new.Header = 'True' THEN 
    SET new.H_order = max(old.H_order) + 1; 
  end IF; 
end
```

Update Query:

```
UPDATE `category` SET `Header` = 'True' WHERE `category`.`ID` = 23
```

Anyone can please help me How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only trigger executing before (or after) update?

Comment: @Frederik.L I am absolutely sure.

Comment: For one thing, max needs a select: `SET new.H_order = (select max(H_order) + 1 from category);`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution for your problem :

**MAX** function is used to return the maximum value of an expression in a SELECT statement. **MAX** function is not possible without SELECT statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER header_true BEFORE UPDATE 
ON category 
FOR EACH row 
begin 
  IF new.Header = 'True' THEN 
    SET new.H_order = (select max(H_order) + 1 from category) + 1; 
  end IF; 
end
```

I hope it will help.